# The grammatical function of "Nor" without "Neither" or "Not" in poetry

Tags: meaning, poetry, lord-byron, dylan-thomas

I've seen a number of examples of poetry, where "nor" appears without a preceding negative. In these examples, I'm unsure of whether I'm meant to understand the sentence as:

- "neither" is elided, so it's really a hidden "(neither) ... nor" sentence
- "nor" is an abbreviation for "and not", so the first part actually has a positive meaning

For example, from Lord Byron's Childe Harold's Pilgrimage, we find the following lines (about Napoleon):

> There sunk the greatest, 
> nor the worst of men, 
> Whose spirit antithetically mixt 
> One moment of the mightiest, and again 
> On little objects with like firmness fixt,

Are we meant to understand this as Napoleon being *neither* the greatest *nor* the worst? Or are we meant to understand it as meaning Napoleon *was* the greatest and definitely *not* the worst?

Similarly Dylan Thomas' poem "I see the boys of summer", there's a stanza that goes

> But seasons must be challenged or they totter 
> Into a chiming quarter 
> Where, punctual as death, we ring the stars; 
> There, in his night, the black-tongued bells 
> The sleepy man of winter pulls, 
> Nor blows back moon-and-midnight as she blows

Are we meant to read the last three lines as meaning, the "sleepy man of winter" *neither* pulls the black-tongued bells *nor* blows back moon-and-midnight? Or are we meant to understand them as saying that the sleepy man of winter *does* pull the black-tongued bells, *but does not* blow back moon-and-midnight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Byron’s use of “nor” is sense 2b in the *Oxford English Dictionary*, where the examples make it clear that “neither” is indicated. Note the 1813 quotation showing that Byron was familiar with this sense.

> **nor, *conj.* 2.** Without immediately preceding (negative) correlative (such as *neither*).
>
> **b.** Without other negative expressed. Now *rare*.
>
> 1594   C. Marlowe & T. Nashe *Dido* v. ii   Though thou nor he will pity me a whit.
> 1621   M. Wroth *Countesse of Mountgomeries Urania* 532   The most ignorant proud woman liuing, caring for, nor respecting any but her selfe and hers.
> 1678   J. Bunyan *Pilgrim’s Progress* 127   They threatned that the Cage nor Irons should serve their turn.
> 1813   Ld. Byron *Bride Abydos* i. xii. 366   A heart his words nor deeds can daunt.
> 1872   Ld. Tennyson *Last Tournament* in *Gareth & Lynette* 103   Great brother, thou nor I have made the world.
> 1954   W. Faulkner *Fable* 348   A world such as caesar nor sultan nor khan ever saw, Tiberius nor Kubla nor all the emperors of the East ever dreamed of.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*</sub>

In *Childe Harold*, Byron makes the sense clear by elaborating the same idea in different words: Napoleon was neither the greatest nor the worst of men; rather, his character contained a mixture of greatness and smallness.

By contrast, Thomas’s use of “nor” is sense 5a:

> **nor, *conj.* 5.** And — not.
>
> **a.** Following an affirmative clause, or in continuing narration. Now chiefly *poetic*.
>
> 1697   J. Dryden tr. Virgil *Georgics* iii, in tr. Virgil *Wks.* 101   His Age and Courage weigh: Nor those alone.
> 1822   Ld. Byron *Heaven & Earth* i. iii, in *Liberal* 1 198   Away! nor weep!
> 1871   R. Ellis tr. Catullus *Poems* lxi. 205   Come nor tarry to greet her.
> 2006   C. McCarthy *Road* 71   The snow fell, nor did it cease to fall.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*</sub>

In ‘I see the boys of summer’, it works best if the “sleepy man of winter” is pulling the “black-tongued bells”, because this is one of the things that makes winter the “chiming quarter” that the seasons are prone to “totter” into.